# Consider removing downvotes when the answer is edited

Tags: discussion, votes

I am referring to this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/any-good-books-about-shiva/2539#2539)

When I saw this much downvotes I thought the culprit was the book '7 Secrets Of Shiva'(it is the edited answer from OP). After reading the comments only, I realized that 'Immortals of Meluha' is the reason for downvotes. Actually the edit misleads people unless they prefer removing those votes. I have put a comment on the same regarding this. What should we do in situations like this? Would it be better to delete the first answer and then suggest OP to post his edits as a new one? Or should we wait to remove all those downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Users tend to check their recently down voted answers. So system allows users to change their votes once an edit is made by the user who originally posted, be it a question or an answer, hence, the other user who down voted the post can now take the down vote back or can up vote as well.

So there is no need to re post your answer as another answer, unless it is a complete different one, minor changes to the post should be edited to the post itself and shouldn't be re answered again.

Also, according to your terminology, you cannot guarantee that the edit made by a user is valid or not, say after I got loads of down vote for my post, I will add a period `.` and will save the edit thus revoking all the down votes doesn't make my answer helpful for anyone. Also if a user edits his post substantially doesn't mean that every edit of a user is correct.

Bottom line is, users can take their down votes back once the user who posts edits his post and rectifies his errors.

Comment: In the specific case we're talking about, the user changed the book recommendation to a completely different book.  That's clearly a case where the old answer should have been deleted and a new answer should be posted, right?

Comment: I agree with Keshav.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, hence I've wrote in the answer already that *So there is no need to re post your answer as another answer, **unless it is a complete different one***